# Use c# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Revision to list changes between two versions of document

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop

I am creating a C# Windows application that will compare two versions of a Word document and save the differences to a file,

So far so good - using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Revision` interface I am able to get the type of change, line and page number of the change, and the text that changed

Problem with this is the changed text returns all of the text (original text and current text) as a single string - I want to be able to split this so I can see the differences more clearly

> EG:
>   If a line is changed from 'hello' to 'Hi how are you', the text I get output from that revision is 'hello hi how are you'

I would like to be able to output this something like "'hello' has been changed to 'Hi how are you'"

is there any part of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Revision` interface that can do this?

Comment: No, you have to do some manual parsing yourself. Just check at the range start and end positions to determine if they point to "same change".